# proxy design pattern using reflection

Tags: design-patterns

I came across the code given below from the following link: http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/proxy-design-pattern/

I am failing to understand the following piece of code:

```
Animal proxy = (Animal) Proxy.newProxyInstance(realSubject.getClass()
.getClassLoader(), realSubject.getClass().getInterfaces(),
new AnimalInvocationHandler(realSubject));
```

Can someone please provide some resource/pointer to help me understand, as i have not done any work on reflection.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

interface Animal {

    public void getSound();

}

class Lion implements Animal {

    public void getSound() {
        System.out.println("Roar");
    }
}

class AnimalInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private Object realSubject = null;

    public AnimalInvocationHandler(Object realSubject) {
        this.realSubject = realSubject;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = m.invoke(realSubject, args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


}

public class ProxyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal realSubject = new Lion();
        Animal proxy = (Animal) Proxy.newProxyInstance(realSubject.getClass()
                .getClassLoader(), realSubject.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                new AnimalInvocationHandler(realSubject));
        proxy.getSound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does that mean? It creates a new Object (the return type), using the ClassLoader and Interfaces of the class to be Proxy-ed. Finally it creates a new AnimalInvocationHandler which then delegates (i.e. calls) to the Proxy-ed object.

From [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) -

```
static Object   newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h)
     Returns an instance of a proxy class for the specified interfaces that dispatches method invocations to the specified invocation handler.
```

"proxy" wraps "lion" and acts like a lion, even though it's not a "lion".
Finally, perhaps this picture will clarify the relationship(s) involved - 
[image]

Comment: You might want to compare this with my blog post for today - http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem may be that, as written, it doesn't appear to do anything very useful :-)

It sets things up such that you have an object, `proxy`, that implements Animal but has no actual class definition visible in your source code. Instead, calls to any method on `proxy` come through to the AnimalInvocationHandler.invoke method. This is standard java.lang.Proxy stuff, often used when you would otherwise have many very similar method implementations (instead you have one piece of implementation code which does something slightly different depending on what method was called).

The difference here is that the invoke method passes straight through to a matching method on an underlying object, adding no useful behaviour (I guess it catches any exceptions, but I assume that's not intended and they were just swallowing the slew of reflection-related stuff for teaching clarity). I guess this makes it more of a true proxy, though.

Presumably the idea is that you would add some behaviour before or after passing through to the real method (ie above or below the `m.invoke(realSubject, args);` line) - would have been clearer if they'd added a comment saying `// add extra behaviour here` or whatever.